# Dask Client fails to connect to cluster when running inside a Docker container

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-kubernetes

I am running Dask Gateway in a Kubernetes namespace. I am able to connect to the Gateway using the following code, while not running in a Docker container.

```
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask_gateway import Gateway

gateway = Gateway('http://[redacted traefik ip]')
cluster = gateway.new_cluster()
```

However, when I run the same code from a Docker container, I get this warning after `gateway.new_cluster()`.

```
distributed.comm.tcp - WARNING - Closing dangling stream in <TLS  local=tls://[local ip]:51060 remote=gateway://[redacted ip]:80/dask-gateway.e71c345decde470e8f9a23c3d5a64956>
```

What is the cause for this? I have also tried running this with `--net=host` on the Docker container, that resulted in the same error.

**Additional Info**: This doesn't appear to be a Docker networking issue... I am able to use the Coiled clusters from within a Docker container, but not the Dask-Gateway clusters...

It appears that the initial outgoing connection from the docker container to the traefik pod succeeds. A dask-scheduler is successfully spun up in the cluster. However, the connection drop (timeout?) that prevents further interactions.